# Why is the integration $\int_{\frac6\pi}^{\frac2{3\pi}}\frac{\cos\left(\frac1x\right)}{x^2}dx$ non-negative?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Why does the following inequality hold?

> $$\int_{\frac6\pi}^{\frac2{3\pi}}\frac{\cos\left(\frac1x\right)}{x^2}dx\ge0$$

I am new to integration so I may be blind to a careless mistake or need my handheld in the answer.

I have gone through the calculation and always end up with 1.5, but I am aware that the upper bound is smaller than the lower bound, and I am supposed to take the negative of my result.

Also from the graph from Wolfram Alpha, I do not understand why they even show a red negative section. I thought we were concerned with just the blue section.

Thank you to all who try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, $\frac6\pi>\frac{2}{3\pi}$, thus note that:
$$\int_{\beta}^{\alpha}{f(x)dx}=-\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}{f(x)dx}$$
You most likely did $$\int_{\frac{2}{3\pi}}^{\frac6\pi}{\frac{\cos(\frac 1x)}{x^2}dx}$$so just take the negative of that.

Comment: Note: it might be useful to mention that the substitution of $u =\frac 1x$ leads to a negative which turns the value positive

Comment: Rhys was right, I was just blind to a dumb srimple mistake even though I checked it almost 10 times. I switched the bounds and took the negative out, but then when actually doing the calculation, I had somehow NOT switched bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $y=1/x$ so $dx/x^2=-dy$ and $$\int_{6/\pi}^{2/(3\pi)}\cos\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\int_{\pi/6}^{3\pi/2}-\cos y dy=[-\sin y]_{\pi/6}^{3\pi/2}=\sin\frac{\pi}{6}-\sin\frac{3\pi}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-(-1)=1.5.$$Note that $\cos y<0$ for $y\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\,\frac{3\pi}{2})$, so the $y\ge\frac{\pi}{2}$ part of the integral over $y$ is actually positive. Equivalently, the original integral includes a positive contribution from $x\in(\frac{2}{3\pi},\,\frac{2}{\pi})$ so that $\frac{1}{x}\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\,\frac{3\pi}{2})$. In both cases the integral also has a negative part, not quite sufficient to make the total negative.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, is another way of viewing it; that I always have to check whether the integral will switch the order fo magnitude of the bounds before calculating? 

So I didn't have to switch them initially becasue the (1/x) just changed switched them again effectively?

Comment: Actually, we calculate the integral with the -sin, so I still dont understand why you are talking about cos?

Comment: @ramose Because if you want to understand whether $int_a^b f(x) dx$ should be positive or negative, the sign of $f$ on $(a,\,b)$ is a useful starting point.